# Prove there exists a $c \in (0,1)$ such that $\int_{0}^{c} f(t)dt = c - 1/2.$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $f:[0,1] \to (0,\infty)$ be a continuous function and $\int_{0}^{1}f(t) dt = \frac{1}{3}.$ Prove that there exists $c \in (0,1)$ such that $\int_{0}^{c}f(t) dt = c- \frac{1}{2}$. I have tried to prove in contradiction but cannot prove. Please provide a hint so that I can prove it on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $g(c)=\int_0^cf(t)\,\mathrm dt-c+\frac12$. What is $g(0)$? And $g(1)$?

Comment: g(0) = 1/2 and g(1) = 1/6.

Comment: Actually, $g(1)=-\frac16$.

Comment: Yes sir, I am sorry, you are right. $g(1) = -1/6.$

Comment: So, $g$, which is a continuous function, changes its sign in $[0,1]$. Doesn't this give you a clue?

Comment: yes sir, there exists a c \in (0,1) such that g(c) = 0. But can we say that g is continuous?

Comment: Wel, let us see. The function $\int_0^cf(t)\,\mathrm dt$ is continuous, $-c$ is continuous and $\frac12$ is continuous. What else do you need?

Comment: Thank you sir. Now I got it...Thanks for the time.